# Create string with trailing spaces in Bash

Tags: string, bash, formatting, whitespace

I'd like to loop over an associative array and print out the key / value pairs in a nice way. Therefore I'd like to indent the values in such a way, that they all start at the same position behind their respective keys.

Here's an example:

```
declare -A my_array
my_array["k 1"]="value one"
my_array["key two"]="value two"
for key in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$key: ${my_array[$key]}"
done
```

The output is

```
k 1: value one
key two: value two
```

The output I'd like to have would be (for arbitrary key length):

```
k 1:     value one
key two: value two
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `printf`, if your system has it:

```
printf "%20s: %s" "$key" "${my_array[$key]}"
```

This hard-codes the maximum key length to 20, but you can of course add code that iterates over the keys, computes the maximum, and then uses that to build the `printf` formatting string.

Comment: Thanks, that's working! I used printf for formatting numbers with leading 0s, but didn't think of using it for trailing whitespaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`. You'll get all the power of formatting, e.g. `%30s` for a field of 30 characters.